# Is there anyway to off-line test Logic App functions?

Tags: azure, testing, azure-logic-apps

Is there anyway to off-line test Logic App functions?

e.g. if I have something like ...

```
"expression": "@equals(
   coalesce(triggerBody()?['Correlation']?['CaseNumber'], 'CaseNumberMissing'), 
   'CaseNumberMissing')",
```

Ok, I can deploy the Logic App to Azure, use Postman to send in a suitable request, and then check in the Portal ...

But this is so slow  :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, due to the way the service works (especially certain bindings) you can only test deployed Logic Apps. Even the Visual Studio extension for local development requires that you're connected to your subscription and the Internet. This is the closest you can get to local development. Maybe Azure Functions is a better choice as it supports local development and debugging.

Comment: Bummer ... got to use Logic Apps, dictated by the client